# TLS Exception. Unknown Secure Transport error 'Closed Graceful'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I keep getting this error `Unknown Secure Transport error 'ClosedGraceful'` even though my `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is returning `true`.

The full stacktrace is ...

```
     at Security.Tls.AppleTlsContext.CheckStatusAndThrow (SslStatus status, Security.SslStatus[] acceptable) [0x000b1] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/AppleTlsContext.cs:170 
  at Security.Tls.AppleTlsContext.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, System.Boolean& wantMore) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/AppleTlsContext.cs:883 
  at Security.Tls.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessWrite (Security.Tls.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:637 
  at Security.Tls.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00086] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:199 
  at Security.Tls.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation () [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:159 
  at Security.Tls.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/Security/Tls/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:140
```

I've even tried adding

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

To `info.plist` but still no luck

Edit: Currently using RestSharp

Comment: This seems to be a bug, I've ran into it as well. Try to use the `ModernHttpClient` NuGet package as a workaround

Comment: I'm currently using RestSharp, but I'll look into ModernHttpClient

Comment: With using ModernHttpClient I still get an error, `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

Comment: Have you tried changing the property iOS Build > Advanced > SSL/TLS implementation  from Apple to Mono?

Comment: @ClintLandry That fixed it for me! Do you know why that is? Will that affect getting accepted through the app store at all? I can do research if you don't know off the top of your head.thanks!

Comment: I do not know off of the top of my head what all the implications are only that the Apple version of SSL/TLS was breaking all of my web service calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property iOS Build > Advanced > SSL/TLS implementation from Apple to Mono.

[image]

Comment: we don't have the option, (SSL/TLS implementation) in VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was Correct but since the current visual studio is not having that option, we need to enter **mtouch argments under iOSBuild-->Code Generation & Runtime-->Additional mtouch arguments**

Comment: and what arguments did you have to add?